# Is the sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I need to tell my boss that I need a leave for a particular day in order to attend holy baptism of my cousin. I am planning to send below sentence for that.

> I need to attend holy baptism of my cousin at St Mary's Cathedral church on 14th September 2014.

Is this grammatically correct? Is it a polite sentence? How can I effectively present it to my boss in one sentence. Please provide your suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a question about a word or usage, please **[edit]** your question to ask specifically about that word or usage. As it is, your question requires _proofreading_ and is off-topic. Our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages explain what is and is not acceptable here; please read them. (In English, a singular, uncountable noun must be preceded by a _determiner_ such as an article.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's basically good.

A couple of small points:

You should say "the" in front of "holy baptism".

A cathedral is a type of church. So unless the official name of the church is "St Mary's Cathedral Church", you would just say "St Mary's Cathedral". If "church" is part of the name, it should be capitalized.

We don't normally put "th" after the day of the month when it is written as part of a full date.

So I'd say:

> I need to attend the holy baptism of my cousin at St Mary's Cathedral on 14 September 2014.

And I'm not sure about this point as I'm not Catholic. But in Protestant circles, we don't normally say "holy baptism" as the name of the event. It's just "baptism", as in, "I'm planning to attend my cousin's baptism." I presume all baptisms are holy so that would be redundant. But maybe that's not the same in Catholic circles.

Anyway, as far as politeness, I think it's perfectly polite. I presume your point is that you are saying that you have to take some time off to attend this event. I'd probably spell that out, like, "I need to take off from 10:00 am to 2:00 pm on Thursday to attend, etc".

I suppose if you want to be really careful about being polite, you could say, "I would like to take time off ..." as opposed to "I need to ...".

Comment: Having been raised Catholic, I will say that we also say Baptism, but we capitalize it.  Also, the official name is either Church or Cathedral, not both.  A cathedral is the seat for a bishop, and is also a church, which is a consecrated place of worship in which a priest says Mass.  If the church is a cathedral as well, the official name is Cathedral.

Comment: I'd point out the date could also be written with a *th* if it's ordered as *September 14th, 2014*, or *the 14th of September, 2014*.

Comment: Maybe this is a national or regional thing, but typically we write the date "September 14, 2014", though we vocalize it as "September fourteenth twenty fourteen". It's more common to add the "th" if you leave off the year, e.g. "This happened last September 14th." "14th of September, 2014" is possible, I guess, though I think pretty rare. When people want to be formal -- like on wedding invitations -- they sometimes get quite verbose and write "the 14th of September, in the year Two thousand and fourteen".

Answer (score -1):

You can improve it by saying :

```
I need to attend my cousin's Holy Baptism at St Mary's Cathedral on the 14th of September 2014
```

Answer (score -1):

According to my Gregg Secretary's Handbook, you only put 14th when you say the 14th of September.  If the date goes after the month, you just say September 14.